# In SED how to a find a line by specific word, substitute the line with another content

Tags: sed

How do I find a line by a word and substitute the whole line with a content?

That is what I have, a variable to insert after Task: + 6 characters
WG="AREA001"

Original:
'Printing - Process: 14052549 Task: 001 LONDON  '

Expected Result:
'Printing - Process: 14052549 Task: 001 AR: AREA001 LONDON '

```
WG = '<subject>Print Card Workgroup XXXXX Task: 001</subject>

cat test1.xml | sed -e "s/<subject>\<subject>$WG" > test2.xml
```

ERROR:

```
/gd: command garbled: s/<subject>/<subject>Print Card Workgroup XXXXX Task: 001</subject>
```

SOLUTION TAKEN:

## cat test.xml | sed -e "s|.*subject*.|$WG|" > t.xml

Comment: You need to escape special chars in your variable, it's breaking the command syntax.

Comment: Also, the assignemnt to `WG` is faulty (can't have spaces around `=`). Could you describe in more detail *which* specific word you're talking about, and what the expected output of your command is? Currently, we have to guess from the code.

Comment: I have tried and same error occurs:     cat test1.xml | sed -e "s/.*<subject>*.\$WG" > test2.xml

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I couldn't maneg to escape the characters so I change the  slach / to pipe |  Command:  cat test1.xml | sed -e "s|.*subject*.|$SUBJECTWG|" > t.xml

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :**

As corrected by @Glenn, the content of the variable $WG contains a `/` and therefore needs to be escaped:

```
sed -e "s/^.*\<subject\>.*$/${WG//\//\\\/}/"
```

---

To replace any line containing the word `<subject>` with the content of the variable `WG`:

```
cat test1.xml | sed -e "s/^.*\<subject\>.*$/$WG/g"
```

As said @Benjamin, you need to remove the spaces around `=` when assigning your variable:

```
WG='<subject>Print Card Workgroup XXXXX Task: 001</subject>'
```

Comment: You have a slash in the replacement text, which will break the `s///` command. use `"s/^.*<subject\>.*$/${WG//\//\\\/}/"` to escape the slashes. Also, your pattern is anchored, so you don't need `g`lobal replacement.

Comment: @glennjackman Absolutely, the slash inside the content of the variable was breaking the substitution. Your escapement method is efficient! I wish there's a `\v` (very magic) mode in sed just like in vim, so it's a bit more readable without escaping everything. Thanks for clarifying the uselessness of the `g` flag, much appreciated.

Comment: WG="AREA"
<subject>Printing - Process: 14052549 Task: 001             LONDON           </subject>                                             
RESULT:
<subject>Printing - Process: 14052549 Task: 001 AR: AREA            LONDON           </subject>